# Is it safe to cancel CHKDSK when it has been started without any parameters?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

I know that it is not a good idea to forcibly stop a `chkdsk` process that has been executed with parameters like `/f` and `/r`.

But is it safe to stop the process when it has been started simply by the `chkdsk`command?
Chkdsk prints out a lot of errors and is continuing very slowly.

I suppose it to should be safe to cancel the process since there should be only in read mode, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. Without command line arguments `chkdsk` is running in a read-only mode and it's safe to stop it at any time.

If you want to be sure nothing bad happens, you should cancel `chkdsk` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. It won't force-close it, but gently tell it to stop instead. After few seconds (or maybe minutes) the program will drop you to the command line.