# Can you stop a chkdsk operation on a usb drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, usb, external-hard-drive, chkdsk

This is an external WD 1TB drive. It is attached to a Dell Optiplex 745 running windows xp, sp 3 with only 4 GB of RAM. is there anyway to stop chkdsk on this drive without hurting the file structure or the drive itself? I really did not even mean to run chkdsk within windows on this drive!  It is in phase 4 of chkdsk and after 2 hrs. only shows one green bar of completion. This drive is for storage only.....it runs no operating system.

Answer (score 0):

It has never been safe to stop CHKDSK once started as there is always a risk of corrupting your data.

If the data on the USB has been backed up you can try stopping it but as noted there is a risk.

Here is more information on this topic.

[https://superuser.com/questions/1252438/how-to-safely-stop-a-chkdsk-r-f-c-on-windows-10#:~:text=You%20can%27t%20stop%20chkdsk,might%20lead%20to%20filesystem%20corruption](https://superuser.com/questions/1252438/how-to-safely-stop-a-chkdsk-r-f-c-on-windows-10#:%7E:text=You%20can%27t%20stop%20chkdsk,might%20lead%20to%20filesystem%20corruption).

Comment: This is both ridiculous and outrageous.  A misplaced option could cause it to take many hours to complete, which one may not *have*.