# Is it possible to pause chkdsk and continue it later?

Tags: hard-drive, chkdsk

Is there any way to pause chkdsk then shutdown the computer then boot it up again and resume from where it was paused?

the full story is hard drive keeps disconnecting and reconnecting so i wanted to run chkdsk with /r but chkdsk apparently requires more than 24 hours to finish this hdd (it's not because of the time shown, it really takes that much time) but the problem is the power goes out once a day everyday so it's impossible to run chkdsk unless there's a way to pause chkdsk and resume it later.

Comment: Have you tried choosing Hibernate from the start menu then booting back up to see if `chkdsk` is still running?

Comment: thank u, i think hibernate is only for laptops.
when i stop it'll just restart when i try it again later.

Comment: Why would you think Hibernate is only for laptops? It's actually *more* useful for desktops -- leave your work on screen at 5 PM, hibernate, and pick up where you left off next morning at 8!

Comment: 1) If something is going wrong with the drive then the first thing to do is make a backup of your data. 2) What makes you think that the disconnections are due to a file system error - is there some additional information you could give us?

Comment: thank u from the responses, i thought a desktop cant hibernate because i dont have a hibernate button after clicking the power button in the start menu, im have no idea what causes the disconnects i just thought a chkdsk could help, computer been getting power outages alot and alot of blue screens have been appearing with messages like hypervisor_error and critical_process_died, i have no idea what they mean. i just thought id start with a chkdsk and then see what i can do from there before the hdd dies

Comment: @jade22 Is it the mains power which fails or only the computer?

Answer (score 0):

CHKDSK is not a bright App - It just does what you tell it to and will not pick up after a restart. It will just start over.

Get the HDD manufacturer's diagnostic App and check the driver for errors.  This is most likely why it is disconnecting trying to run CHKDSK.

You can also try CHKDSK without the fix parameter to see if it runs faster and picks out drive errors.  A drive test App is better.

Answer (score 0):

According to the post
[How to safely stop a `chkdsk /r /f C:` on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1252438/how-to-safely-stop-a-chkdsk-r-f-c-on-windows-10)
stopping `chkdsk` by power cut is not always safe.

Some flags can make
[chkdsk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk?tabs=event-viewer)
go faster:

> - `/i` : Use with NTFS only. Performs a less vigorous check of index entries, which reduces the amount of time required to run chkdsk.
> - `/c` : Use with NTFS only. Does not check cycles within the folder structure, which reduces the amount of time required to run chkdsk.